# When using XSLT 2, Schematron ignores rules that have attributes in their context

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-2.0, schematron

I've discovered that Schematron ignores any rule that has a `context` attribute that contains a reference to an attribute. In the following code, I have `@att` but any complex xpath that contains an attribute is subject to the problem. (e.g. `bar/@att` would also be ignored.)

I am using the version of Schematron distributed [here](http://www.schematron.com/tmp/iso-schematron-xslt2.zip).

I have this `test.sch`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<schema
    xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"
    queryBinding="xslt2"
    schemaVersion="ISO19757-3">
  <title>Test schema.</title>
  <pattern>
    <rule context="@att">
      <assert test="false()">@att cannot appear anywhere.</assert>
    </rule>
    <rule context="foo">
      <assert test="false()">foo cannot appear anywhere.</assert>
    </rule>
  </pattern>
</schema>
```

This `test.xml` file:

```
<foo att="something"/>
```

And for the sake of replicability, this `Makefile`:

```
SAXON:=saxon
SCHEMATRON_TO_XSL:=/home/ldd/src/schematron/xslt/iso_svrl_for_xslt2.xsl

.PHONY: all
all: test.xsl test.xml
    $(SAXON) -xsl:$< -s:$(word 2,$^)

test.xsl: test.sch
    $(SAXON) -s:$< -o:$@ -xsl:$(SCHEMATRON_TO_XSL) allow-foreign=true generate-fired-rule=false

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm test.xsl
```

If I issue `make clean; make`, I get exactly one failing assertion:

```
<svrl:failed-assert test="false()" location="/foo[1]">
   <svrl:text>foo cannot appear anywhere.</svrl:text>
</svrl:failed-assert>
```

**Schematron has ignored the test in `<rule context="@att">`, which should also fail. Why is the rule ignored?**

Note that if I change `test.sch` to use `queryBinding="xslt1"` and edit the `Makefile` to change `SCHEMATRON_TO_XSL` to use the schematron transformation for XSLT 1, I do get the two failures that I expect. So the problem occurs only when using XSLT 2.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in Schematron that seems to have been present in Schematron's code probably since at least 2010, and certainly since 2011. (When it exactly came into being is hard to tell since AFAIK there's no public version control repository for Schematron. Look at the end of this answer to know why I say it was *certainly* present since 2011.)

#### Explanation

If you inspect your `test.xsl` file generated from the Schematron, you'll see `xsl:apply-templates` elements like this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*|comment()|processing-instruction()" mode="M1"/>
```

Note how attribute nodes are not part of the `select`.

The code that executes when you run `saxon` to convert your `test.sch` file imports the schema named `iso_schematron_skeleton_for_saxon.xsl`. If you inspect that file, you'll find that the `xsl:apply-template` elements that appear in your XSL are generated with code like this:

```
<axsl:apply-templates select="{$context-xpath}" mode="M{count(preceding-sibling::*)}"/>
```

(`axsl:` is not a typo. It is the namespace prefix used by the output nodes.)

Looking backwards in the same file, you'll find:

```
<xsl:variable name="context-xpath">
  <xsl:if test="$attributes='true' and parent::node() ">@*|</xsl:if>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$only-child-elements='true'">*</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$visit-text='true'">node()</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>*|comment()|processing-instruction()</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

And:

```
<xsl:param name="attributes">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="//iso:rule[contains(@context,'@') or contains(@context,'attribute')]">true</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>false</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:param>
```

The problem is with the way `context-xpath` is initialized. It is a top-level variable, which is initialized once, and only once. At the time of initialization, the context node is the rood node of the document so `parent::node()` is always false, and consequently `@*|` is never included in the value of `context-xpath`.

In my experience `attributes` is initialized properly. So there's no need to fiddle with it.

Note that when you run the Schematron stylesheets for XSLT 1 processors, a different code base is used, which does not have this bug. (The XSLT 1 equivalent to `iso_schematron_skeleton_for_saxon.xsl` is `iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl`).

#### Solution 1: Rewrite your rules

It is possible to rewrite the problematic rules so that they do not have a `context` that refer to attributes. I can't say I'm a fan of this solution because it complicates the rules and could have a serious negative performance impact. And there may be cases where rewriting the rules is impossible.

#### Solution 2: Edit `iso_schematron_skeleton_for_saxon.xsl`

I no longer experience the problem when I edit to file so that `context-path` is initialized this way:

```
<xsl:variable name="context-xpath">
  <xsl:if test="$attributes='true'">@*|</xsl:if>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$only-child-elements='true'">*</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$visit-text='true'">node()</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>*|comment()|processing-instruction()</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

In general, I don't like ad-hoc edits to third-party code but I don't see a better solution.

#### Corroboration

After I had done the investigation above, I had a good idea of what keywords would help me find any issue report on the topic so I started searching for `context-xpath` and similar keywords. I found that Ken Holman ran into this same problem in December 2011, as evidenced by [this email](http://markmail.org/thread/yazce2sgv3nox5et). He came to conclusions similar to mine. He also suggests forcing the `attributes` parameter to be true. In my experience it has not been necessary. The case he mentions is one where the Schematron code is split amongst multiple files but the `readme.txt` for Schematron says the first step of processing should be to run `iso_dsdl_include.xsl` to combine the multiple parts of a schema into one file.

AFAIK Ken Holman's email never received a response, and the problem was never fixed in any "official" sources.

Comment: In the meantime there is a public repository: https://github.com/Schematron/schematron/ - and this issue was file at https://github.com/Schematron/schematron/issues/29